# Why does Terraform string interpolation syntax results in a list?

Tags: terraform

Consider the following example in `terraform console`:

```
> "${[1,2,3]}"
[
  1,
  2,
  3,
]
```

Why does Terraform evaluate this expression to be a list, and not a string representation of that list?

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#interpolation

Answer (score 2):

This would be expected behavior in a high-level/interpretive language and/or DSL. If you want a string result, then you should not interpolate:

```
> "[1,2,3]"
"[1,2,3]"
```

Comment: I imagine the question is a simplified example. How would you do that when the list is stored in a variable, and not literally in the string?